# Beamer theme which gives looks similar to revealjs

Tags: beamer, presentations, themes

I'm looking for a Beamer  theme which mimics the look of the default [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js) theme. Slides created with reveal.js can look like this:

[image]

(A complete demo you can find [here](https://revealjs.com/#/).) I am just curious whether there exists some ready-made Beamer theme achieving this bold large-letter look.

PS: A [google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&biw=1280&bih=695&ei=Wh0zXbTaB-36z7sPsdCjwAQ&q=beamer+theme+%22reveal+js%22&oq=beamer+theme+%22reveal+js%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5559.10952..11312...0.0..0.338.1593.0j6j1j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i13i30j0i8i13i30.2N4mif7OKUg&ved=&uact=5) brought up that there are vice versa some reveal.js themes mimicking various Beamer themes, but not the other way round - and that's what I'm looking for!

Comment: As I read it the question is not actually about a beamer theme but how to replicate the font in TeX, is that accurate?

Comment: @DaiBowen  No, that's not correct! I am curious whether somebody knows of a drop-in theme for Beamer so that I can without further customization generate slide shows which look similar to reveal.js slide shows (apart from the JavaScript transition effects, of course).

Comment: crosspost: https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/25306/kennt-jemand-ein-beamer-theme-welches-das-layout-von-revealjs-diavoragen-nachahmt

Answer (score 2):

From a [Commentary on the German  TeXWelt](https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/25306/kennt-jemand-ein-beamer-theme-welches-das-layout-von-revealjs-diavoragen-nachahmt) I got the following hint:

The beamer theme ***Focus*** (see [GitHub - elauksap/focus-beamertheme: Focus: a minimalist presentation theme for LaTeX Beamer.](https://github.com/elauksap/focus-beamertheme)) is a good starting point.